# Improve return type for CRUD GET list or details objects

Tags: api, api-design, json

When creating the crud `GET` methods to get a list of items, or the details, what should I return? The whole object properties for both cases? Or just the properties that are necessary? I'm asking this because it may be related to a future api that I call to change some of the products status.

For example, imagine the following API endpoints:

- /api/product
- /api/product/[id]

The first one would return a list with all the products on the database and the second one would return the details for the product. So should the list of all products contains all products properties? Or just the properties that are relavant to display on the list?

Usually the list will contain the following properties:

```json
{
  id: number;
  is_active: boolean;
  is_feature: boolean;
  thumbnail: string;
  name: string;
  sku: string|null;
  price: number;
  stock: number;
}
```

While the product details would contain much more information, for example:

```json
{
  id: number;
  is_active: boolean;
  is_feature: boolean;
  thumbnail: string;
  name: string;
  sku: string|null;
  price: number;
  stock: number;
  description: string;
  description_short: string;
  category: number[];
  tag: number[];
  attributes: number[];
  ...
}
```

My question regarding this "problem" is because I have some methods to handle products information that should return the object or at least part of it.

In this case I have the properties `is_active` and `is_feature` so I can change the products status to either be visible/hidden on the website or even create have it displayed as a featured product on the homepage.

In order to change this status I would call the following endpoints, that can be called both from the list view or the product details view.

- /api/product/status/[id]
- /api/product/feature/[id]

So when calling these 2 methods, should I make some special treatments to return the list object or the details object? Should I just return the new status/feature value? Like `{is_feature: false}` or should I return nothing in case it succeed?

This is why I want to plan all this, because if both `/product` or `/product/[id]` returns the same object type, I can make `status` and `feature` also return the whole object. But the whole object doesn't make sense to use on the list, as I just need a couple of information.

Comment: For pure REST it might be sufficient to only have links to the full object in the list, possibly using query parameters to control the level of detail. Endpoints that change resources don't have to directly return that resource, they can also just provide a link to it (See also: the See Other HTTP code). But all of this tends to lead to more network requests, more latency. Using a design like "backend for frontend" can help here, where your API is designed to deliver exactly what a certain client needs.

Comment: @amon Yes, I have the list and in order to manage the product the user must access it's details, with the exception of the status and featured status, this can be changed from the list, as it's just a toggle. But name, description, etc. Must be done within products details. I don't plan to make the api dynamic to return properties based on the request, it's either the list, details or maybe just one of them, depending on answers I get here to analyze the situation.